# How to access data from a loop in a vuetify carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use vuetify to make a kind of carousel to display recipes that are stored in the database.
But I would like when I click on a recipe the carousel opens below a space with all the elements of the recipe in question (the one we clicked on) So I found a component on vuetify that corresponds exactly to what I'm looking for: [Here is Vuetify Carousel](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups/#pseudo-carousel)

But in my `v-slide-item` I use a loop that retrieves the recipe data but suddenly from the `v-expand-transition` I no longer have access to this loop how can I display the recipe data suddenly?

Here is the code :

```js
<template>
    <v-sheet
        class="mx-auto"
        elevation="8"
        max-width="100%"
        style="box-shadow: none !important;"
    >
        <v-slide-group
            v-model="model"
            class="pa-4 slider"
            show-arrows
        >
            <v-slide-item
                v-for="n in Object.keys(recipes)"
                :key="recipes[n].id"
                v-slot="{ active, toggle }"
            >
                <v-card
                    :color=" 'grey lighten-1'"
                    class="ma-4 card-recipe"
                    height="200"
                    width="200"
                    style="border-radius: 10px;"
                    v-bind:style="recipes[n].recipe[0].first_recipes_image != null ? {  backgroundImage: 'url(' + recipes[n].recipe[0].first_recipes_image + ')' } : {  backgroundImage: 'url(https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg)' }"
                    @click="toggle"
                >
                    <p class="card-text" ><span class="black--text">{{ recipes[n].recipe[0].name }}</span></p>
                    <v-row
                        class="fill-height"
                        align="center"
                        justify="center"
                    >
                        <v-scale-transition>
                            <v-icon
                                v-if="active"
                                color="white"
                                size="48"
                                v-text="'mdi-close-circle-outline'"
                            ></v-icon>
                        </v-scale-transition>
                    </v-row>
                </v-card>
            </v-slide-item>
        </v-slide-group>

        <v-expand-transition>
            <v-sheet
                v-if="model != null"
                height="200"
                tile
                style="background-color: #FFF8F0 !important;"
            >
                <v-row
                    class="fill-height"
                    align="center"
                    justify="center"
                >
                    <h3 class="text-h6">
                        Selected {{ model }}
                    </h3>
                </v-row>
            </v-sheet>
        </v-expand-transition>
    </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

    export default {
        props: {
        },
        data: () => ({
            model: null,
            recipes: [],
            openedCards: [],
        }),
        computed: {
            console: () => console,
            ...mapGetters({
                plantActive: 'permatheque/getPlant',
            }),
        },
        methods: {
           async getPlantRecipes() {
          this.$axios
            .$get("/lnk/plant/recipes?plant_id=" + this.plantActive.id + "")
            .then((response) => {
              this.recipes = response;
              console.log(this.recipes);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
    },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getPlantRecipes()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope I was clear enough, thanks!

Comment: shouldn't your url be `const url = '...?plant_id=' + this.$store.getters.plantActive.id)` ? read more in the documentation - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: @balexandre my function `getPlantRecipes` is working properly but i would like to be able to access the data of this function also in the `v-expand-transition` but i don't know how to do it because i don't have access to the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the v-model of the `v-slide-group` which is basically the index from recipes array of the selected item in the carousel.

This way you know which recipe is selected, so you can go grab the recipe info from the array or make another api call to get that info.

### Example

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71474788-recipes-carousel-6vm97o?file=/src/components/Example.vue

If you already have the recipe info within your recipes array, all you need to do is use the v-model variable of the `v-slide-group` which I renamed to `recipeIndex` to access that data directly from your array.

```html
<v-expand-transition>
    <v-sheet v-if="recipeIndex != null" tile style="background-color: #FFF3E0 !important;">
        <v-container fluid class="pa-12">
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <span class="text-h6">{{ `${recipes[recipeIndex].name}'s Recipe` }}</span> <br>
                    <span class="text-subtitle-1">{{ recipes[recipeIndex].description }}</span>
                    <p class="text-justify mt-4">
                        {{ recipes[recipeIndex].steps }}
                    </p>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img :src="recipes[recipeIndex].image" alt="Beach Scene" style="width: 100%;" />
                    </div>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-sheet>
</v-expand-transition>
```

If you need to get the info from a secondary api call. You can set up a watcher on the recipeIndex variable to obtain the recipe info everytime it changes.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! But how do I use the v-model in my recipes array?

Comment: The recipe info is already in the array? Since you already know the recipe index, you can make some computed props to retreive the recipe info of the selected recipe from the array. You can also set up simple methods and execute them with a watcher when the v-model changes. I can set up an example in codesandbox for you.

Comment: That would be very nice thank you, that way I would understand better and yes the recipe info is already in the array thanks to the call to api function

Comment: Alright, working on it. The thing is that you don't need to create the recipes info while you're looping the array. You can go grab the info later when a recipe is clicked. And the `v-expand-transition` works like a template. I'll update my answer when it's done.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I just added a practical example on my response, assuming you already have the recipe info in your array. I got hungry making this haha.

Comment: Thanks very much!! You unblocked me! Your example was very clear and that's exactly what I wanted thank you again and sorry for making you hungry haha